# Calling super constructor in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have classes such as AccountsController, ProductsController etc that all inherit from BaseController. Unity sets up my services as needed. These classes also all require a _sequence service.  As it is a common requirement for all classes I would like to code this in the BaseController.

```
public class AccountsController : BaseController
{
    public AccountsController(
        IService<Account> accountService) {
        _account = accountService;
    }

public class ProductsController : BaseController
{
    public ProductsController(
        IService<Account> productService) {
        _product = productService;
    }


public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IService<Account> _account;
    public IService<Product> _product;
    protected ISequenceService _sequence;

    public BaseController(
        ISequenceService sequenceService) {
        _sequence = sequenceService;
    }
```

But how can I do this? Should I set up a call to the BaseController inside the constructors of each of the AccountsController and ProductsController?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can chain [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx):

```
public class ProductsController : BaseController
{
    public ProductsController(
        IService<Account> productService) : base(productService)
    {
        _product = productService;
    }
}
```

Note that the chained `BaseController` (using the [`base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword) has been passed the `productService` parameter, tough this can be anything.

Update:

You *could* do the following (poor mans' dependency injection):

```
public class ProductsController : BaseController
{
    public ProductsController(
        IService<Account> productService) : base(new SequenceService())
    {
        _product = productService;
    }
}
```

Or, pass in the dependency on `ISequenceService` through your inheriting types:

```
public class ProductsController : BaseController
{
    public ProductsController(
        IService<Account> productService, ISequenceService sequenceService) 
        : base(sequenceService)
    {
        _product = productService;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand your example. What I need is to construct the BaseConstructor and the sequenceService.

Comment: Saw your comments about DI but already I am using Unity for dependency injection. Can't I do this with Unity? I am wondering how Unity works because already it sets up my AccountController and feeds instances into it. What if I just make a call to the BaseController. Will Unity not catch this and set up the SequenceService automatically?

Comment: @Samantha2 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329399/unity-not-injecting-dependencies-defined-in-base-class